# How to programmatically reparametrize a bezier curve for constant speed

Tags: parametric, curves, bezier-curve

I have a Bezier curve defined as follows:

```
public Vector3 Evaluate(int segment, float t)
{
    float oneMinusT = 1 - t;

    var p0 = points[segment];
    var p1 = p1Points[segment];
    var p2 = p2Points[segment];
    var p3 = points[segment + 1];

    return oneMinusT * oneMinusT * oneMinusT * p0 + 3 * oneMinusT * oneMinusT * t * p1 + 3 * oneMinusT * t * t * p2 + t * t * t * p3;
}

public Vector3 EvaluateDerivative(int segment, float t)
{
    float oneMinusT = 1 - t;

    var p0 = points[segment];
    var p1 = p1Points[segment];
    var p2 = p2Points[segment];
    var p3 = points[segment + 1];

    return 3 * oneMinusT * oneMinusT * (p1 - p0) + 6 * oneMinusT * t * (p2 - p1) + 3 * t * t * (p3 - p2);
}

public Vector3 EvaluateSecondDerivative(int segment, float t)
{
    float oneMinusT = 1 - t;

    var p0 = points[segment];
    var p1 = p1Points[segment];
    var p2 = p2Points[segment];
    var p3 = points[segment + 1];

    return 6 * oneMinusT * (p2 - 2 * p1 + p0) + 6 * t * (p3 - 2 * p2 + p1);
}
```

Basically, someone chooses the points along the spline (the `points` array above), intermediate points are then calculated automatically to keep the spline smooth (`p1Points` and `p2Points`).

If one was to choose points with equal increases in `t`, the resulting points would obviously have varying distances, because the space between 2 control points is mapped to [0...1] on `t`. I need to reparametrize this curve so that, given some parameter `x`, equal increases in `x` result in equal distances travelled along the curve. I barely passed my math courses in college, so ...

Comment: Not sure I can help much, but I guess you're after something like $x(t)=ts^{-1}$ where $s(t)$ is the arclength function as your new parameter?

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding the process. Would it be possible for you to reformulate it mathematically or produce a diagram to explain?

Comment: See the section on cubic bezier curves: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bézier_curve

Comment: @Shuri2060 I guess that's what I need...

Comment: Sounds like you might be looking for an arc length parameterization of the spline. That computation is likely to get ugly.

Comment: @amd yes it is. Thing is, my current solution is also ugly. I'm approximating (numerically) the total arc length at some ~1000 points and caching them. Then, to find the point at distance d, I'll find the lower and upper bounds of d among the cached distances using a binary tree search and interpolate between those. As I said, ugly. And imprecise.